# Filtering Data in Excel using a Button/Box

Tags: excel

I have a large data set in excel with a data filter on it. I want to create a box or button that can be pressed and it will filter data for me.

For example I have a long list of fruit, I want a button that says "Apple" and then all the data related to apples will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do would probably be best accomplished using a macro. [Here](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/macro-buttons-filters/) is a good resource on how to do exactly what you are asking.